# codeigniter form_dropdown

Tags: codeigniter

how to disable option in drop down box using code igniter?i want to disable the value"------"in this drop down

```
       echo "<tr class='background1'><td class='checkoutfield'>";
       $countryall='';
       $select='';
       if(isset($order)) $country=$order['varShippingCountry']; else $country='';
       if(isset($countries) && $countries !='') {
           $countryall['']="Select";
        foreach($countries as $key=>$value):
        $countryall["226/United States"]="United States";
      if($value['id'] !='226') {
//<option value=”spider” disabled=”disabled”>Spider</option>
      $countryall['0']="-------------------------------------------------------";
 $countryall["$value[id]/$value[varPrintableName]"]=$value['varPrintableName'];

       }
        if($value['id'] == $country)
        $select="$value[id]/$value[varPrintableName]";
       endforeach;
         }
          $selFunc='style="width:190px;" id="varShippingCountry" class="required" onchange="stateajax(this.value)"  onKeyup="return changeText(\'varShippingCountry\',\'varPaymentCountry\',\'this.value\')"';
        echo form_label('Country','varShippingCountry')."<span class='mandatory'>*</span></td><td>";
```

echo form_dropdown('varShippingCountry',$countryall,$selFunc);

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable an item in a HTML select element - only disable the entire element.

Are you trying to make a separator between different sections of the list? In that case, you can use `<optgroup>`.

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

You can make this happen in CodeIgniter by passing it a multidimensional array.

Alternatively, if you are just trying to make the first and default item look like ------, then add it in the normal way with an empty value. Then on validation, check that an empty value has not been passed.